# Can I perform an SQL query from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

Right off the bat, I'm quite sure that this isn't the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve, so guidance in that sense is welcome.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

> Create a HTML button (onclick) to run a JavaScript function that will query a MySQL database and return table data, which I can then display with HTML and style on the front end.

HTML Code (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script rel="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script rel="text/javascript" src="db/db_connection.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <button onclick="get_weapons()">Connect to DB</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (db_connection.js)

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: 'app_db'
});


/// Wrap this in a functon to be triggered only when a button is pressed?
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM weapons", function (err, result, fields){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

The database is running on WAMPP and I'm also using node.js

Comment: generally no - you'd have to find a compatible browser based sql client

Comment: If you're running node.js, you can use AJAX in the browser to call a node.js API that performs the query.

Comment: @DanielA.White well, `chrome.sockets.tcp` and the proposed [Raw Sockets API](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6398297361088512) notwithstanding...

Answer (score 0):

In the client side context is not possible.

In the server side you can use Node to interact with your SQL database.